# Spin doctor Essentials II pump not working properly

Tags: repair, pump

I attach the pump head to the presta valve. It attaches properly and even a few PSI, like about 10 psi, go in and then the pump handle just wants to spring up and is very difficult to push down. I can get it to compress but it no longer inflates the tire to any higher pressure. What would cause this? It doesn't appear I can disassemble this pump.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't unscrewed the top knob on the Presta valve.

Comment: You have to unscrew the Presta valve nut a few turns

Comment: I'm a very experienced cyclist. I unscrewed the presta valve. It's actually a friend's pump. It happens on his bike tires and it happens on mine. It's possible to make a mistake sometimes, but not every time. I wish the solution were as simple as you suggest. Maybe I didn't make it specific enough. The tire actually pumps up to about 10 psi, but then won't go any higher.

Comment: I just tried the pump on two more wheels just to be sure I didn't make a dumb mistake. Same result on those wheels.

Comment: That pump has a double-sided chuck.  Apparently you flip a lever one direction or the other to select which side is working.  I suspect that there's a "trick" to fitting the chuck to the valve, possibly involving flipping the lever first, before fitting to the valve, or possibly involving waiting until the chuck is fit to flip the lever.  And you probably need to be sure to press the chuck ALL THE WAY onto the valve, which may take an extra bit of effort.  (Hint: Read the instructions.)

Comment: Yes I'm flipping it the correct way. It starts to inflate properly and there are no air leaks. It is on the valve securely and correctly. It is a bit tricky to make it work. I just tried to flip the lever the other way. It does flip and seems to be OK until you begin to pump. Air leaks and none goes into the tube. Again, the pump does start to work OK, then it stops inflating and the pump handle is being forced upward with air pressure. The pumping action can be continued, with some difficulty, but with no increase in the tire's air pressure beyond the initial 10 psi.

Comment: Should I add that, although this is not my pump, I have owned one in the past just like it. I learned I don't like this kind of pump and bought a better one. This pump chuck has two sides. One for presta and one for schrader. If you try to use the wrong side, you will have less luck than I am now having.

Comment: So, assume I'm actually competent enough to attach the pump correctly. What then could cause the problem I am having?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's something having to do with the chuck.  There is a sort of valve in the chuck that switches the airflow between sides.  If it gets sort of stuck in the middle it will block all airflow.  One possibility is that, as you pump in air, the chuck slides off the wheel's valve stem slightly, causing the valve inside the chuck to get stuck in the middle.

Comment: I'll have someone hold the chuck in place. I don't think that is the issue because there are never any air leaks. I think if the chuck were slipping out of place air would begin to leak around it. Or it might just pop off due to the increasing pressure from continued pumping. I already told my friend it is time for a new pump. This type of pump chuck is just dumb, even when it works properly. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Not an answer, but it is possible to just replace/upgrade the chuck and possibly the hose on many types of track pump.  So then it should work a lot better.

Comment: Does the pump work when it's not attached to a valve?

Comment: Based on discussion, it sounds like it's broken. If you want to keep the pump or save some money, you can try if it works without the chuck and plug in a new one if it works. SKS has some nice ones available for little money, Silca has some nice and very expensive ones.

Comment: This is a cheap pump. Not worth spending money on it. Thanks.